# Does Hibernate enable L2 cache by default?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, second-level-cache

I'm using JPA with Hibernate impl.

Does Hibernate enable L2 cache by default? Or does it need to be explicitly enabled?

Comment: EntityManager is in JPA not hibernate.

Comment: Show some code so we can help you.Imagining your words is very difficult task here.

Comment: If some other application is accessing the same database as yours, why do you bother about your local application cache? Your application or DAO layer implemented with Hibernate JPA does not cache anything and in-fact does not do anything unless it is written to act in such a way.
@Shoaib,
There is in fact hibernate implementation of JPA specification (Jboss's JPA implementation provider)

Answer (score 1):

JPA has 2 levels of caching:

The first level of caching is the persistence context. The JPA `EntityManager` maintains a set of Managed Entities in the Persistence Context. The first-level cache is mandatory and can’t be turned off; it also guarantees object identity inside a transaction.

JPA second level `(L2)` caching shares entity state across various persistence contexts. Use of the second-level cache is optional. When enabled, entities that are not found in persistence context, will be loaded from `L2` cache, if found.

If you are using Hibernate JPA persistence provider, the `L2` caching is not configured by default. But the support for second level cache in EclipseLink is turned on by default. Below statements are copied from [HERE](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching):

> By default EclipseLink uses a shared object cache, that caches a
>   subset of all objects read and persisted for the persistence unit. The
>   EclipseLink shared cache differs from the local EntityManager cache.
>   The shared cache exists for the duration of the persistence unit
>   (EntityManagerFactory, or server) and is shared by all EntityManagers
>   and users of the persistence unit. The local EntityManager cache is
>   not shared, and only exists for the duration of the EntityManager or
>   transaction.
>
> The shared cache can also be disabled. This can be done using the
>   persistence unit property:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

So, if you are using Hibernate persistence provider, you don't need any special configuration because the `L2` caching is not configured by default. And if you are using `EclipseLink`, you can disable it as above.

Answer (score 0):

you can control level 2 caching in hibernate, however level 1 caching is mandatory.

follow http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm